# TightVNC port remapping not working for web based viewer

Tags: port-forwarding, vncserver

The problem:

I am trying to access my desktop from home, but the firewall setup at my workplace blocked most of the ports but a few. The blocked ones include 5900 and 5800 for TightVNC viewer and java based web viewer

I have then tried to change the port specified in TightVNC setup (both Server and Service Mode) from 5800 to 22, which I know is one of the few that still kept open to external network. I still can't access it through the web based viewer after this change.

Question:

Why is this the case?
Is there a general way to change the port of a certain server/services without touching the router (which is out my reach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Actual* Problem - You wish to bypass the security at your work on your own.

The Solution - Ask Permission.

Port 22 is the default for SSH, and thus is most likely already being used at your work... and that's why it is left open in their firewall.

Since your work has actually locked down pretty much all access (except the ports they use) that tells you that you should be talking to the IT department there to see if they can open a port for you.  However, I would expect to be disappointed, since most businesses that actually take the time to lock down ports don't WANT their employees having this kind of access (or this kind of activity during work).

You can't expect to use some port scanning service to find open ports, and then just switch to one of them and expect the service to work.  This is one of those times that instead of attempting to circumvent their security, you need to *ask permission*.  Yes, they are most likely going to ask you why you need to access your desktop computer from work.

As a side note, if you REALLY need to access your desktop from work, get an Android based smart phone, install an Android VNC viewer, and use your mobile 3G or 4G connection to connect (instead of a work WiFi connection).  Don't complain about the screen size though.  Doing it that way would enable you to play all you want while you are at work.  If you aren't attempting to play on your home desktop, but actually attempting to access work files that are stored on your home computer, then you should consider using a service like Google Drive or Dropbox.